# Angular2.JS files with d.ts files WITHOUT npm Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core, aurelia

Does anyone know of a **recent** blog post or tutorial on which angular 2 .js files along with the appropriate d.ts files I need so I can just drop them into an existing VS solution **without** using NPM? I see that I can get the angular files [here](https://code.angularjs.org/), but not sure which ones I need. According to the Angular docs, I [need do nothing to get typings files for library packages that include d.ts files—as all Angular packages do.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html), but again, when I look thru a sample Angular app, don't know which d.ts files I need.

I can't stand bloat and clutter. Below is a brand new asp.net core on .net 4.6 on the left, the same thing on the right after  following [this blog](http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/08/08/setup-angular2-typescript-aspnetcore-in-visualstudio.html):

[image: Absurd bloat and clutter!]

I can't stomache having to add over 13,000 files to get ahold of maybe 20?, 30? files.

Maybe I'm being too OCD about this, but right now I'll take any suggestions to avoid that bloat, even going with another front-end framework. I've briefly looked at Aurelia, which I like, but again, NPM. Not sure React is appropriate.

My business domain includes `Category`, which is a self-referencing class/table, and I'm after an intuitive UI where the user can quickly create their own `Category` structure without having to do a bunch of post-backs to the server. Seems with either Angular2 or Aurelia, I'd only need a couple of `Component`s to accomplish this in the browser.

I know Angular 1.5 added `Component`s, and I may explore that if need be. From what I understand about React, it's not for data management.

So to reiterate my questions, can I get just the Angular2 files along with their d.ts files so I can code in typescript? If not, the same question for Aurelia. And if not, any way that I can keep bloat down yet still write some elegant front-end code.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what's not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Questions asking for external resources are off-topic, as are questions asking for opinions (Aurelia vs Angular 2). Currently your question reads like a rant about how JavaScript development works these days (which is to say, a large number of small components which are built up to get the functionality one needs).

Comment: New front-end frameworks typically involve building tools, which involve package managers, which involve NPM. If you don't want to use NPM or any other package manager you should use a simpler javascript library such as KnockoutJS.

Comment: Personally I don't suggest using angular2 or any frameworks more complex than jQuery etc. w/o NPM or bower. You could only use the umd modules (`bundles/**/*.umd.js` files) and either include them in html or use systemjs to dynamically load them and you may get away with it **if** you only use javascript, but angular has plenty of dependencies and you lose all the typed language features you get with typescript and a proper id. You just wont do yourself a big favor, if you try to use it way off the intended way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for Development purposes yes your Angular 2 stuff will be massive (its annoying but necissary) however as I am sure you know, once you build your angular app for production (using angular cli for example) it cuts all those 40,000 files down to about 10. for example this is my application before and after production...

[image]

and after

[image]

So I would guess you want to build your angular stuff out first and then drop it in you application

Comment: not sure what you mean. Create another solution, then use npm to pull in angular, then use angular cli to build it, then copy and paste some files? Will i lose intellisense in my typescript?

Comment: I am suggesting this for production purposes only, So my application for example is a angular 2 front end with a .net core api backend. I used 2 seperate solutions and then merged them for production. So I used npm with angular cli in my favorite editor and used VS for my api. I am not sure if this is "best practice" but it worked well for me.