# How to make lighter my Angular2 app created with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have very simple app, created using angular-cli. It weighs a lot, when i using only a few modules(Component,Input,NgFor,FormsModule). When i tried to remove some unused package - server does not get up. 
How to remove unused package? On may is possible to download packages from web?

Comment: look at my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128423/angular2-js-files-with-d-ts-files-without-npm-visual-studio-2015/41128656#41128656 I post pictures of before and after of project size as well as why it is so massive in developement.

Comment: so can i used it as a single app for example in apache?

Comment: Yea you should be able to.

Comment: How i can do it? I moved whole dist catalog into apache, and it does not work - he has problems with reading scripts

Comment: not sure, try googling and looking around.  here is a site I found https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2 I am not too familiar with apache. I just know its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng build --prod --aot` to use it in production,
it will remove all the unnecessary packages and
compiles it into a tiny package
 which will be on `dist` folder in your `angular-cli` project.

So don't worry about the size .
Hope this helps

Comment: Few tiny packages was created, but packeges from node_modules were not removed. What should i do with dist - folder content?

Comment: The dist folder is your full site so put the dist folder in somewhere which can be served by `apache` or `nginx` like `/var/www/htdocs`